# Rspec controller testing undefined method `mb_chars'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I'm testing post controller that registered user can create post.

```
  it 'should allow registered user to create post' do
    user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
    sign_in user
    expect {
      article_params = FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:post)
      post :create, :article => article_params
    }.to_not change(Post, :count)
    response.should redirect_to(new_user_session_path)
    flash[:alert].should == "You need to sign in or sign up before continuing."
  end
```

And i get an error

```
Failure/Error: post :create, :article => article_params
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `mb_chars' for nil:NilClass
```

It's because i have generate_slug in my model.
Post.rb

```
include Translit
#slug
before_validation :generate_slug

def generate_slug
  self.slug = translit(title)
end
```

And in Translit.rb i have mb_chars

```
# encoding: utf-8
module Translit
def translit (string)
table = {
  "ё"=>"yo","№"=>"#",
  "а"=>"a","б"=>"b","в"=>"v","г"=>"g",
  "д"=>"d","е"=>"e","ж"=>"zh","з"=>"z",
  "и"=>"i","й"=>"y","к"=>"k","л"=>"l",
  "м"=>"m","н"=>"n","о"=>"o","п"=>"p","р"=>"r",
  "с"=>"s","т"=>"t","у"=>"u","ф"=>"f","х"=>"h",
  "ц"=>"ts","ч"=>"ch","ш"=>"sh","щ"=>"sch","ъ"=>"'",
  "ы"=>"yi","ь"=>"","э"=>"e","ю"=>"yu","я"=>"ya"
  }

  string = string.mb_chars.downcase

  table.each do |translation|
    string.gsub!(/#{translation[0]}/, translation[1])
  end

  string.parameterize
end
```

end

Thanks for help

My factories.rb is

```
FactoryGirl.define do
factory :user do
  email "testspec@gmail.com"
  password "password"
  password_confirmation "password"
end

factory :post do
  title "Deploying through ssh"
  body "This is post about ssh"
end
end
```

Comment: Your title value is nil...

Comment: My factories.rb has   factory :post do
    title "Deploying through ssh"
    body "This is post about ssh"
  end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a controller spec, not a model spec so don't test your model.

```
Post.any_instance.stub(:generate_slug)
```

I also strongly suggest you only do one test per spec. You are currently doing three specific tests and also indirectly testing sign_in as well. I stub out the login aspects of all my controller specs, and test logins work through my request specs.

I hope that helps.